# springboot circular dependencies casue in tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm handle with a very old projects,which truly got a circular dependencies

----here's the code

```
public class BService{
@Autowired
private AService aService;
}
```

in the meantime,

```
public class AService{
@Autowired
private BService bService;
}
```

The strangest thing happened,I run with springboot(which is embeded tomcat),It could run as usual.
After I package it(by the way,I changed the main application,and pom with provided tomcat and exclude embeded tomcat) to war.

when I deploy it to tomcat.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

|  xxxx.xxx.aService 
|   xxxx.xxxx.bService
```

#### here's my question

the precondition,I can't change the code.

- why I could run it as usual when I use embeded tomcat
- why it will show circular dependencies in tomcat when I package it to war and deploy

Comment: but springboot-run won't show

Comment: Try `@Autowired @Lazy private BService bService;`